# Nginx won't serve php pages on IPv6

Tags: nginx, php, debian, php-fpm, ipv6

I have a Debian 8 server running nginx with php5.  The server is configured with IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and I can ping the server successfully on either address.  I can also browse to an html page on the server successfully with either address.  I can browse to a php page successfully if I use the IPv4 address, but if I try to browse to the php page using the IPv6 address, the browser hangs, and I can't see why.  phpinfo says IPv6 is enabled. Any help would be much appreciated.  Config files are below.

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
server {
server_name abcwiki;
listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/dokuwiki;
    index index.html index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        include /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

**/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf**

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

Other nginx and php files are left at the default.

PHP info shows:

```
PHP Version 5.6.30-0+deb8u1


System  Linux ABCWiki 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64  
Build Date  Feb 8 2017 08:50:44  
Server API  FPM/FastCGI  
Virtual Directory Support  disabled  
Configuration File (php.ini) Path  /etc/php5/fpm  
Loaded Configuration File  /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini  
Scan this dir for additional .ini files  /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d  
Additional .ini files parsed  /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/05-opcache.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-readline.ini  
PHP API  20131106  
PHP Extension  20131226  
Zend Extension  220131226  
Zend Extension Build  API220131226,NTS  
PHP Extension Build  API20131226,NTS  
Debug Build  no  
Thread Safety  disabled  
Zend Signal Handling  disabled  
Zend Memory Manager  enabled  
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring  
IPv6 Support  enabled  
DTrace Support  enabled  
Registered PHP Streams https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip 
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2 
Registered Stream Filters zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk
```

Comment: Is there anything in your application's logs relating to this, and/or any relevant nginx logs you could update your question with?

Answer (score 2):

I've tracked down the cause of this which is a bit of a red herring.  This was caused by our SonicWALL firewall VPN dropping packets using the full MTU (I think it's a bug in the firewall and am taking that up with SonicWALL).  The html pages I tested were small and so never caught this.  Reducing the MTU on the server to 1374 (leaving the one on the firewall set at 1500) has resolved the issue for now.

Comment: You should check if the firewall blocks ICMPv6 packets. This would break IPv6.

Comment: Please update their reply / bugfix if it was a bug.

Comment: Now had some feedback from SoniWALL and done some more testing.  The SonicWALL VPN has a link MTU of 1422.  When it gets the packet size 1500 from the server, it drops this, and replies with an ICMPv6 Packet Too Big message, which it seems is the right thing for it to do under IPv6.  The Debian / Nginx server should then re-send the data using a smaller packet size, but it doesn't - it keeps trying to send packets with size 1500.  So it looks like this is in fact an issue with Debian (or at least with my Debian configuration).